# How does process substitution work with while loops?

Tags: bash, pipe, pipeline

I'm reading/editing a bash git integration script

This snippet is supposed to print `${SYMBOL_GIT_PUSH}` or `${SYMBOL_GIT_PULL}` alongside how many commits i am behind and/or ahead by.

```sh
local marks
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^## ]]; then
        [[ $line =~ ahead\ ([0-9]+) ]] && marks+=" ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${SYMBOL_GIT_PUSH}"
        [[ $line =~ behind\ ([0-9]+) ]] && marks+=" ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${SYMBOL_GIT_PULL}"
    else
        marks="${SYMBOL_GIT_MODIFIED}${marks}"
        break
    fi
done < <(git status --porcelain --branch 2>/dev/null)
printf '%s' "$marks"
```

Example:

```
 4↑ 10↓
```

It is working, but i am trying to understand it.

Why is there some `IFS` and how does it work with process substitution?
I've heard process isn't defined in `sh`. Is there a way to do this the `/bin/sh` way or at least more efficiently?

I was provided with [a link](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS) that should explain what `IFS` does.

---

I switched mixed up things and managed to remove the process substitution:

```sh
local marks
git status --porcelain --branch 2>/dev/null |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^## ]]; then
        [[ $line =~ ahead\ ([0-9]+) ]] && marks+=" ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${SYMBOL_GIT_PUSH}"
        [[ $line =~ behind\ ([0-9]+) ]] && marks+=" ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${SYMBOL_GIT_PULL}"
    else
        marks="${SYMBOL_GIT_MODIFIED}${marks}"
        break
    fi
done
printf '%s\n' "$marks"
```

But now, the value of `$marks` isn't saved and it prints nothing.
I was provided with [another link](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) that explains why.
Will return and update on what i've found.

---

I used the command grouping workaround and wrapped the loop and the print statement inside curly braces:

Also, i made the `/bin/sh` version almost functional (the exception - show how much commits i'm ahead or behind, not hard, i'm sure i'll do something with awk or cut).
I took advantage of fact that `grep` returns non-0 when nothing matches.

```sh
git status --porcelain --branch 2>/dev/null | {
    SYMBOL_GIT_PUSH='↑'
    SYMBOL_GIT_PULL='↓'
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        if echo "$line" | egrep -q '^##'
        then
            echo "$line" | egrep -q 'ahead' && marks="$marks $SYMBOL_GIT_PUSH"
            echo "$line" | egrep -q 'behind' && marks="$marks $SYMBOL_GIT_PULL"
        else
            marks="*$marks"
            break
        fi
    done
    printf ' %s' "$marks"
}
```

This was a fun learning experience! Thanks to everyone who helped. When i find the 100% solution i'll update this.

Comment: So what is not working? What do you want to improve?

Comment: Put your code in a script and add `#!/bin/sh` as the shebang and paste it to https://shellcheck.net  that should give you something to start with. Also `sh` does not have regex but globs, but if you really need regex then you need to use an external utility, like `grep`, `sed` or `awk` and friends.

Comment: and regarding the process substitution, when it is combined with a redirection − like in your example − `command … < <(command2 …)` can be rewritten in terms of a mere pipe, `command2 … | command …`

Comment: To understand what `IFS` means, see: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS

Comment: There is a link posted by @codeforester, It should tell you what `IFS` does.

Comment: Replacing with a pipe has an important difference: the command is run in a subshell, see [BashFAQ/024](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024). For the example in the question, `marks` would be empty in the end, so it's definitely not equivalent here.

Comment: @BenjaminW. @PaulFilipenco indeed that wouldn't not yield the same semantics, so maybe the script should be rewritten to something like `git status --porcelain --branch 2>/dev/null | { while … done; printf '%s\n' "$marks"; }`

Comment: `VAR=value command` will create/modify `VAR` in the environment variables used when running `command`.

Comment: @PaulFilipenco BTW when you'll have obtained the final version of your script that addresses your initial question, feel free to post an *answer* to your own question and accept it, which is actually the recommended practice on SO (see e.g. [What is the appropriate action when the answer of a question is edited into the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))

Comment: I'd recommend using `grep -q` instead of `grep > /dev/null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the bashism-less git info function.

```sh
__git() {
    git_eng="env LANG=C git"
    ref="$($git_eng symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2>/dev/null)"
    [ -n "$ref" ] && ref="$SYMBOL_GIT_BRANCH$ref" || ref="$($git_eng describe --tags --always 2>/dev/null)"
    [ -n "$ref" ] || return;

    git status --porcelain --branch 2>/dev/null | {
        SYMBOL_GIT_PUSH='↑'
        SYMBOL_GIT_PULL='↓'
        while IFS= read -r line
        do
            if echo "$line" | grep -E -q '^##'
            then
                echo "$line" | grep -E -q 'ahead' &&
                    marks="$marks $SYMBOL_GIT_PUSH$(echo "$line" | sed 's/.*\[ahead //g' | sed 's/\].*//g')"
                echo "$line" | grep -E -q 'behind' &&
                    marks="$marks $SYMBOL_GIT_PULL$(echo "$line" | sed 's/.*\[behind //g' | sed 's/\].*//g')"
            else
                marks="$SYMBOL_GIT_MODIFIED$marks"
                break
            fi
        done
        printf ' %s%s' "$ref" "$marks"
    }
}
```

`sed` searches for `[ahead` and deletes it, as well as everything before it, then it pipes it into another `sed` which deletes everything past `]`. This way only the number remains.